# Configure Application Permissions in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, katana

### Background

I have a Web API registered in Azure AD and secured using WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication (OAuth2 bearer token).  This is a B2B-type scenario where there are no interactive users - the applications calling the API are daemon-like background apps.  As such, I don't need any consent experience - I just want trusted applications to be able to call the API, and other applications - even if they present a valid OAuth token - to be denied.

### What I've tried

[This sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet) seemed to describe my scenario almost exactly.  However, the way it determines if a caller is a trusted app or not is by comparing the clientID presented via a claim by the caller to a hard-coded value.  Obviously you could store the list of trusted clientIDs externally instead of hardcoding, but it seems like I should be able to accomplish this via configuration in the AAD portal so that a) I don't have to maintain a list of clientIDs, and b) I don't have to write my own authorization logic.

It seems like I should be able to define a permission for my API, grant that permission to each calling app in AAD (or a one-time admin consent), and then in my API just check for the presence of that permission in the `scp` claim.

From looking at the portal it seems like this is what Application Permissions are intended for:
[image: permissions]

I can create a permission just fine via the application manifest.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to specify that it's an Application Permission, not a Delegated Permission!  I tried changing the `type` from User to Admin as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx), but that seemed to have no effect.

```
"oauth2Permissions": [
{
  ...
  "type": "Admin",
  ...
}
```

### Question

Am I correct that Application Permissions are the best solution for my scenario?  If so, how do I configure it?  Or, as I fear, is this yet another feature that is On The Roadmap™ but not currently functional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ben, Application Permissions are declared in the appRoles section of the manifest. Indeed, if you declare an appRole called say 'trusted' in your resource application's (storage broker demo) manifest - it will show up in the Application Permissions drop down there. Then, when you assign that Application Permission to the client app - the access token that the client app will receive using the client credentials OAuth flow will contain a roles claim with value 'trusted'. Other apps in the tenant will also be able to get an access token for your resource app - but they wont have the 'trusted' roles claim. See this blog post for details: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

Finally, the above way to assign an application permission to a client app only works when both the resource and client application are declared in the same directory - if however these apps are multi-tenant and a customer will install these apps separately - a global admin from customer's directory will need to consent to the client app - which will result in the application permission getting assigned to the instance of client app in the customer's tenant. (my blog post covers this too)

Hope this helps.

ps: if you're stuck - feel free to ping me on the contact page of http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: So does defining an `oauth2Permission` with `Type: Admin` mean it's still a delegated permission, but is consented to once by an admin instead of by each user?

Comment: How exactly does the admin consent in this case? I'm trying to see where as an admin I can click the 'consent' button. Any pointers would be appreicated.

Comment: @TheSenator did you ever figure out how the admin consents? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Joon I totally gave up on this, I think that perhaps there was a technology gap or a brain gap at the time I was looking. For now I've dropped it in favour of a local auth service. But other services to look at include auth0 who seem to be quite good - if a little pricey.

Comment: @TheSenator haha I feel your pain :-)  I had a look in the new Azure portal and when you are a directory admin user there is a "Grant Permissios" button on the Required permissions blade of the app registration. I clicked that and the permissions worked.

Comment: @Joon good work! I'll take a look at that once I stop fighting with other changes in the latest and greatest of the coding world :) thanks for taking the time to tell me!